# How do Blockchain.info recovery mnemonics encrypt wallet data and what prevents hacking of the algorithm?

Tags: wallet, security, blockchain.info, hacking

How do mnemonics encrypt wallet data and what prevents hacking of the algorithm?

For example Blockchain seems to encrypt all data using a mnemonic yet doesn't hold customer data server side.

What prevents creating numerous Blockchain wallets, recording the mnemonics and discovering the algorithm?

**NB.** The BCI mnemonic recovery protocol is **NOT** the same as BIP39

Comment: FYI, I've done some research, and it appears mnemonics at blockchain.info for example work like this: **[11 words encoding wallet ID & checksum]** + **[words encoding passphrase, 1 word per 2 character combination]**

Answer (score 1):

Edit:
Blockchain.info is [open source](https://github.com/blockchain/My-Wallet/blob/ddbb0995fbdb2b5f22bef9eb92a26e2bfefb6e00/account.js#L90), the algorithm is public. The mnemonic that they use stores information about your wallet id and your password only.

Previous answer: You should read into [BIP 39](https://github.com/bitcoin/bips/blob/master/bip-0039.mediawiki) this covers how mnemonics map to the values that are used to create a [HD wallet](https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/Deterministic_wallet) the algorithm is very well known and corresponds to the size of the key space needed for wallet generation.  There are generally [2048 words](https://github.com/bitcoin/bips/blob/master/bip-0039/english.txt) in the wordlist used to create a wallet. A 12 word seed generates 128 bits of information (and 4 check bits). That's 11 bits per word from a list of 2048 words.

Comment: Thanks Mark, the question title is ambiguous (I'm changing it now) as I am actually not referring to BIP39 mnemonics, but rather the old (circa 2011-2015) BC.info password recovery mnemonics